# How can I progmatically click a link in a Winform Web Browser control?

Tags: winforms, com, webbrowser-control

I would like to know how to programatically click a link from with in a Winform Web Browser control.

```
 foreach (HtmlElement linkElement in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A"))
            {
                if(linkElement.InnerText == "Helpful Tips")
                {
                  //Click Functionality
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this using the [InvokeMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.invokemember.aspx) method. Something along these lines:

```
linkElement.InvokeMember("Click")
```