# How to click on a web page link automatic?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

The following code is where the link I need to click on is buried.

I have figured out how to browse to the website and log into the website programmatically.  But, now I need to be able to automatically navigate the site and I have not been able to manage this.

The line that contains "Time Clock Entry" is the link that I need to click...

I am new to coding.  This is my first project.

Sorry.  I did not realize that my earlier copy/paste had been shortened. I have corrected the line that contains the link.

Again, thank you.

```
<div id="dockedContent" class="dockedContent">

    <div id="RecentlyVisitedWidget" class="recentlyVisitedWidget">

    <h2 id="ctl00_12_12_RecentlyVisitedLabel"></h2>
    <ul class="recentlyVisitedLinks">
        <li>
            <span id="ctl00_12_12_Repeater1_ctl00_link">
                <a href="#" onclick="recentlyVisitedSelect('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=ESS!MenuID=2147!PageRerId=2147!ParentRerId=72','72','2147','2147', false, false, 'Time Clock Entry', true)" title="Time Clock Entry">Time Clock Entry</a>    
                </span>
            </li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419306/how-can-i-progmatically-click-a-link-in-a-winform-web-browser-control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the link with this:

```
HtmlElement link = (from HtmlElement elem in webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
                    where elem.GetAttribute("title") == "Time Clock Entry"
                    select elem).ElementAt(0);
```

This basically says "get all `a` tags in the document (and thus all links), and then filter so that I get only `a` tags with a title of `Time Clock Entry`. Once you've done that, give me the first such element."

And then programatically click it with this:

```
link.InvokeMember("Click");
```

Comment: That got me much closer than before.  I understand the logic to it, I am just not experienced enough to troublshoot the error that I got from the first lin...

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @SeanConnelly Oh my bad, didn't realize that `HtmlElementCollection` doesn't derive from any collections, but in fact from `object`. I'll fix my answer momentarily.

Comment: @SeanConnelly Edited and tested.

Comment: {"Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter name: index"}

Comment: By the way... That is a runtime error.  Looks fine when in the edit screen.

Comment: @SeanConnelly Yup, just figured out what your error is. It is due to malformed HTML. In `onclick="recentlyVisitedSelect('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=…,'72','2147','2147', false, false, 'Time Clock Entry', true)"` you're missing a `'` before `'72`. It should be `onclick="recentlyVisitedSelect('pages/VIEW/UTMEntry.aspx?USParams=PK=…','72','2147','2147', false, false, 'Time Clock Entry', true)"`, Once I fixed that my answer worked just fine.

Comment: So.  Is there a way for me to compensate for the issue?  I do not have access to the server.  I can only view the web pages.